# Обязателен параметр Q_OBJECT при разработке под Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-faq

Суть вопроса как бы вырисовывается из заголовка.

Дзен-парни, работающие часто с `Qt` — подскажите.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Если ваш класс никак не наследуется от `QObject` и не использует сигналы и слоты - то данный макрос не нужен, даже если вы используете `Qt` библиотеки в своем коде.
Так что ответ - нет, не обязателен.